# Batch update returned unexpected row count from update (Spring/Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

Right now I have 3 tables in my database - Booking, Restaurant and RestaurantTable. I have a one to many mapping between Restaurant and RestaurantTable (a restaurant can have many tables, but a table can have only one restaurant). I have a file called "newTable.jsp" that inserts new tables to the restaurant. But when I try to do that it gives me the following error:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

I think it's trying to access a RestaurantTable that does not exist yet? But I don't know how to fix that.

Here is my "Restaurant.java" class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="restaurant_name")
    private String restaurantName;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<RestaurantTable> table;

    // Getters and setters
```

My "RestaurantTable.java":

```
@Entity
@Table(name="restaurant_table")
public class RestaurantTable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="table_size")
    private int tableSize;

    @Column(name="table_number")
    private int tableNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id")
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    // Getters and setters
```

My "newTable.jsp"

```
<body>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/menu.jsp"/>
<div id="body">
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

        <h2>Add New Table</h2>

        <form:form method="POST" commandName="table" modelAttribute="table">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Table size:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="tableSize" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Table number:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="tableNumber" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>

    </section>
</div>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/footer.jsp"/>

</body>
```

My RestaurantTableController:

```
@Controller
public class RestaurantTableController {


    @Autowired
    private RestaurantService restaurantService;

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantTableService restaurantTableService;

    @RequestMapping(value="restaurant/table/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addRestaurantTable(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("table", new RestaurantTable());
        return "newTable";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "restaurant/table/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addRestaurantTable(@PathVariable Long id, @ModelAttribute ("table") RestaurantTable table) {
        // Get a Restaurant object and add the table to it.
        Restaurant restaurant = restaurantService.getRestaurant(id);
        Set<RestaurantTable> tableSet = restaurant.getTable();
        tableSet.add(table);
        restaurant.setTable(tableSet);
        restaurantService.updateRestaurant(restaurant);
        return "editRestaurant";
    }

}
```

The {id} in RestaurantTableController is a Restaurant id, it is passed along from "editRestaurant.jsp". Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: My updateRestaurant method:

```
@Override
public void updateRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.update(restaurant);
    logger.info("Restaurant record updated successfully, Restaurant Details=" + restaurant);
}
```

Comment: Show the updateRestaurant method, please

Comment: @itpr I edited my post. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RestaurantTable` entity doesn't have ID at that time, so hibernate throw exception. Try to use `merge` method instead of `update`

> [update](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#update(java.lang.Object))
>
> Update the persistent instance with the identifier of the given detached instance. If there is a persistent instance with the same identifier, an exception is thrown.